# how to sort a dictionary by value in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I am using dictionary and inserting values in it.

Now i want to sort the dictionary by values based on condition. How can i do that?

```
let dealCodes: Dictionary<string> = new Dictionary<string>();
dealCodes.AddUpdate(node.data.dealCode, node.data.dealCode)
```

the result of dictionary is as below:

```
items
  A0zhr: "A"
  A0zhw: "C"
  A0zhz: "B"
```

Comment: do you have an example of the dictionary content ?

Comment: @SupunDeSilva i have added in the question

Comment: You should use other data structure. Dicrionary is by default unordered data structure. It is better to get array of keys and then sort it

Comment: @captain-yossarian can you give me an example on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you implement **Dictionary** by yourself, general objects in JS sorts by key by default.

You can opt to something like follows

**Component**

```
@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public originalData: {} = {
    A0zhr: "A",
    A0zhw: "C",
    A0zhz: "B"
  };

  public sortedData = [];

  name = "Angular " + VERSION.major;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.sortedData = [];
    Object.keys(this.originalData)
      .sort((a, b) => (this.originalData[a] > this.originalData[b] ? 1 : -1))
      .map(x => {
        console.log(x, this.originalData[x]);
        this.sortedData.push([x, this.originalData[x]]);
      });
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<h3>Original Data</h3>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of originalData | keyvalue">{{item.key}}::{{item.value}}</li>
</ul>
<h3>Sorted Data</h3>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of sortedData">{{item[0]}}::{{item[1]}}</li>
</ul>
```

**Hacked up example**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wp2naf

Comment: I get dynamic values into the array so i created a array and pushing elements into it this.originalData.push([node.data.dealCode, node.data.portfolioCompanyName]) but here i see that index is automatically added and which acts as a key instead of my actual key.

Comment: @Ekta can you create a snippet in stackblitz in share please ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on this  example. Keep in mind it is pseudocode, because I don't know you Dictionary implementation :

```js
const dictionary = new Dictionary<string>();
const sortedKeys = Object.keys(dictionary).sort();

sortedKeys.forEach(elem=>{
  console.log(dictionary[elem]) // yuo should see sorted output: A, B, C
})
```